# Unable to set Azue Key Vault Key as "Exportable"

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to store I private key within the key vault of Azure that I might require to export later.

The following image displays the information Azure shares with me once I try to generate or import a key:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVqGy.png)

Sadly the link this "help" is pointing to is not helpful at all:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/confidential-computing/confidential-vm-overview#confidential-os-disk-encryption

So my questions are: how can I create a custom policy within the Azure CLI? All I was able to find there are the standard ones like:

`az keyvault set-policy --name testvault1 --key-permissions all --object-id <id>`

I saw examples of JSON structured custom policies but did not find anything about their syntax or how to load them into the system.

Therefore, can someone please explain how I create such a custom policy for exporting the keys and how the JSON file would need to look like?

I tried to set a custom policy that allows me to export the keys from an Azure key vault.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a sure answer for this, but my understanding is that exportable keys are only for a really specific case with Azure Key Vault and you can't set a key of your own as exportable.

What you could do is store the key as a certificate and that one you can export.

Comment: Hey @juunas, interesting thought. The only issue I see with this is that azure requires the files to be pics12 encrypted pfx files - and I did not find an openssl command that allows to me create something like this for a key file.

What I used for the certificates is the following command:
openssl pkcs12 -inkey client-key.pem -in client-crt.pem -export -passout pass:$password -out client-crt.pfx

If I use the client-key.pem as the -in parameter as well, this will not work. Or am I getting you wrong?

Comment: Hey @juunas, I just tried to store it as a certificate - which works. Problem now is that Azure requires me to wrap it with yet another password when I import it. This results in the file that I download to not be the original .pfx file that I uploaded (shachecksum differs) - and therefore I cannot open it via openssl. Do you have any clue how I get rid of this additional password wrapper?